# Generate random binary arrays with a specific range of ones

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to generate random binary arrays with specific range of ones, e.g.,if I have 6 vectors each of 6-bits and a range of 1s from 1-3 then my result would be for example `([1,0,0,1,0,0],[1,0,0,0,0,0],[1,1,0,0,0,0],[1,0,1,0,0,1,0], etc)` i.e. gives me some combinations of 0s and 1s and uses the range of 1s I gave.

I am using:

```
arr = np.array([1] * K + [0] * (N-K))
np.random.shuffle(arr)
```

to generate vectors with specific number of 1s and I am using:

```
arr2 = np.array([1] * (K-K+1) + [0] * (N-1))
np.random.shuffle(arr2)

arr3 = np.array([1] * (K-K+2) + [0] * (N-2))
np.random.shuffle(arr3)

arr4 = np.array([1] * (K-K+3) + [0] * (N-3))
np.random.shuffle(arr4)

arr5 = np.array([1] * (K-K+4) + [0] * (N-4))
np.random.shuffle(arr5)
```

and concatenate these together with 'axis=0' to have the vectors I want, but this idea is not efficient and I want something to make it more random and more clever.

thanks

Comment: What exactly do you find inefficient about it? And to make sure I understand: for the case where the "range" is from 1 to 3 inclusive, and the array length is 6, you want one randomly chosen array with one 1 in it, one with two 1s, and one with three?

Comment: Well, firstly the inefficient thing about it is that the function I am using will always give me the number of arrays always divisible by 4 which I don't want I want it to generate an arbitrary number of arrays. 

Secondly, I want the number of arrays chosen randomly with one 1 or two 1s or three 1s for example 6 arrays can have three arrays with three 1s and two arrays with one 1 and one array with two ones for example.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this ?

```
while arr.sum() != total_of_1:
    arr = np.random.randint(2, size=(r, c))
```

where `r` is the number of rows and `c` is the number of columns.

Comment: Yes, I did try this and didn't work for me because I don't have control on the number of 1s in the output array.

Comment: If you want something really random and assuming we aren't talking about big matrix:                                                                       `while arr.sum() != 6:
    arr = np.random.randint(2, size=(6,3))`